# GridView Export to PDF Error Not Supported

Tags: c#, pdf, gridview

Here is my *Export ActionResult* to **PDF**:

```
List<DailySum> lstDailySum = db.DailySum.Include(x => x.codeACl).Include(x => x.codeCou).Include(x => x.codeAgc).Include(x => x.AInfo).ToList();

GridView gv = new GridView();
if (Session["Paging"] == null)
{
    gv.DataSource = lstDailySum;
}
else
{
    gv.DataSource = Session["Paging"];
}

gv.DataBind();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DailySumExport.pdf");
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.Charset = "";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gv.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Now this works fine when I try and export to Excel but when I try and export to PDF I get this error message:

> Adobe Acrobat Reader DC could not open 'DailySumExport.pdf' because it is either not supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

Any help on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: All you're doing here is outputting HTML to the response stream and telling the client it's a PDF; there is no way that is going to work.  You need to use something like iTextSharp to create PDFs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707916/usercontrol-export-gridview-to-pdf

Comment: This can "work" for DOC and/or XLS, because MS Word and/or Excel is able to figure out that the content is actually of HTML format, but this is actually a trick (a bad one) which will result in MS Office application throwing a warning dialog, when opening that file, saying that the file's extension and file's format are different. Also this approach will not work for pretty much anything else (including a newer formats like DOCX and/or XLSX and also PDF).